# When to use lock statements in concurrency

Tags: c#, asp.net, concurrency

I am having trouble understanding the way to use the `lock()` statement in my code.  I have a couple static collections like so:

```
private static Dictionary<string, User>() Users = new Dictionary<string, User>();
```

I constantly add, remove, update, and read from this collection.  I realize that when I add, remove, or update I should be locking the `Users`, but when I read from the collection do I have to lock it?  What is the correct way to do something like search for a key and return the `User` in the Dictionary? I was thinking creating a new `Dictionary` instance and then copy Users to that and then read from it, or can I just read directly from it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best option here would likely to be removing the locks, and using `ConcurrentDictionary<string, User>` instead of a `Dictionary<string, User>`.

Otherwise, you will need to synchronize your reads as well.  You can read from multiple threads, but if a writer will be writing to the dictionary while readers are reading, you need synchronization.  `ReaderWriterLock` (or `ReaderWriterLockSlim`) work well in this scenario, as they can allow multiple readers, but only a single writer.  A simple `lock` will also work, but will block more often than required.

Comment: Isn't ReaderWriterLoc(Slim) an overkill with respect to the locking time for such a simple operation like adding/removing/reading of a Dictionary?

Comment: @DirkBonné It completely depends - it is often the most appropriate mechanism (though in .NET 4, I'd just use ConcurrentDictionary).  If you have a lot of readers, but occasional overlapping writers, this will perform better than a lock, since a lock will block concurrent reads.

Answer (score 3):

> but when I read from the collection do I have to lock it?

Yes, if it is possible that another thread may modify the dictionary during the read.

> What is the correct way to do something like search for a key and return the User in the Dictionary?

Use the [TryGetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013.aspx) method.

If you are using .Net 4.0 or greater, you can use the [ConcurrentDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) collection, which is thread-safe.

Comment: If you're *only* reading, there is no need to lock.  If you're reading and someone else may or may not be writing at the same time, then you need to lock.

Comment: @Servy - thanks for pointing that out, I should have been more specific; answer updated.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using `C# 4.0` or more, you can make use of [ConcurentDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx) which handles all that stuff.

If you don't have or can not use `4.0` for some reason, yes, you need to implement by yourself locking mechanism on `Read`, `Write` and `Contains`, to simulated basic [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) principles, like

- Consistensy
- Isoltaion
- Durability.

Don't think *Atomicity* has much deal in this case.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This only ensures that each individual operation appears atomic.  If you are ever performing multiple methods that depend on each other you need to `lock`.

Comment: @Servy: give me a time to write something :)

Comment: Atomicity does; as observed from the outside, all methods called on `ConcurrentDictionary` are atomic (not strictly true with those that take a `Func` but if they are functional `Func` - and there's a reason they have that name - then their perhaps being called more than once won't be observed).

Answer (score 0):

You can use ConcurrentDictionary

LIink : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx